# Issue running Nuxt3 app in Azure Web App slot

Tags: azure, nuxt.js, azure-web-app-service, nuxtjs3

With Nuxt2 I've had no issues deploying or running apps on Azure App Service, but found that I'm having trouble with Nuxt3. All the docs I've read on Nuxt3 mention Azure Static Web Apps but nothing about Azure Web Apps. I have no issues deploying to my development slot though receive this message when navigating to the app url:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Monitoring the application logs doesn't show anything. I'm sure this is something to do with my app setup/config though I can't make heads or tails of it.

1. How would the backend config of a Nuxt3 app deployed to an Azure Web App differ from the config for an Azure Static Web App [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs)?

Answer (score 1):

I tried deploying **`Nuxt Starter App`** from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs) **in my Azure Web app** ***instead of Azure static app*** and it was successful, Refer below:-

*My Azure Web App:-*

**OS:- Linux**

**Runtime Stack - Node-18-lts**

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

***Added start up command in the Azure Web App > Configuration > General Setting to start the Nuxt app in Azure Web app correctly:-***

[image]

```bash
npm run dev -- -o
```

**The Nuxt app loaded successfully like below:-**

[image]

*The Permission error occurs for Azure Web app Windows OS, As the NuxtJs app causes some error while loading:-*

**Make sure to add the start command in the package.json like below before deploying in Windows OS Azure Web app:-**

```bash
{
  "name": "nuxt-3-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Nuxt 3 Test",
  "author": "Nuzhat Minhaz",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev -- -o",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.6"
  }
}
```

I'd recommend using Linux based Azure Web app for the nuxtjs deployment like above.

Comment: What is the error that is caused when running on a Windows OS? I would rather not switch to Linux if it is not required.

Comment: Also why are you using `npm run dev -- -o` for an app deployed on production?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Using Linux OS is better as the path to your web app is handled correctly specifically for nuxt app. In windows app you need to set the path in Path mappings to site/wwwroot/appname. npm run dev -- -o I have used this command from this official MS document on deploying nuxt app in azure static web app- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs you can use another startup command like npm start too