# Enable http to https redirect for Azure Static Web App that uses enterprise-grade edge

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

The URL https://example.com works but http://example.com doesn't. It says not found, instead of redirecting. I'm using enterprise-grade edge and not Azure Front Door.

I have searched the documentation and couldn't find how this can be done in the portal or through `staticwebapp.config.json`.

Please note that this is not Azure web app or Azure static app hosted in Azure storage, or Azure app service.

Comment: why do you want it to? most sites now don't offer the http version.

Comment: Because some of our users type in example.com in the browser and that leads them to http[://]example.com for some reasons, and I got complains that the site is down, but it's not. I only need to redirect the request to https

Comment: Please note that this is not Azure web app or Azure static app hosted in Azure storage, or Azure app service. > If its not either of this, Where is your app hosted? Also refer my SO answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77393607/can-i-use-http-api-in-static-azure-web-app/77395121# to enable Http in your url as this is the only option.

Comment: It's Azure Static Web App. It's not the same as Azure Web App, you said it yourself in the comment you link

Comment: The default URL http[://]randomhash.azurestaticapps.net will redirect you to the https. This one is a normal "Static Web App". Is the problem with the custom domain or the default?

Comment: tbh i haven't messed with them much but how about this: 

https://brettmckenzie.net/posts/redirect-http-traffic-to-https-in-azure-cdn/

Comment: This is a custom domain. @EnenDaveyBoy it looks like I will need to figure out how to hook up Azure Front Door/Azure CDN to the Azure Static Web App. There is no configuration option in the Enterprise-grade edge approach

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing EnenDaveyBoy's comment's suggestion, But after adding the Http Redirect rule to my Azure CDN origin the Http redirection was not supported, As my Azure static web app was hosted from a storage account. Refer below:-

***Error:-***

[image]

Also, When I added the static web app URL's origin to the Azure CDN endpoint, It still redirected to **`https://`** by default.

When I used added a **simple static web app** with **Enterprise grade edge enabled** **without serving the site from storage account** and implemented the solution with Rule set configuration **my CDN URL Endpoint still did not get routed to http successfully**:-

[image]

**Rule set:-**

[image]

**Origin groups:-**

[image]

Route:-

[image]

**Custom Domain CDN:-**

[image]

When I routed to my CDN Endpoint it routed me back to my **`https://`** custom domain:-

[image]

[image]

One alternative is to use Azure Web App instead of Azure static web app Disable Https only setting from web app. Refer my SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77393607/can-i-use-http-api-in-static-azure-web-app/77395121#).